# How to call Google Apps Script encapsulated function from html template

Tags: google-apps-script

Hi I am using Google App Scripts on a Google Sheet and I wanted to organize my code, so I tried encapsulating some of the functions.  However, I can't seem to figure out how to call the encapsulated functions from the html templates.

Does anyone know if it is possible to call an encapsulated function with google.script.run from an html template?

Example:

Code.gs

```html
function onOpen(e){
  var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Document Routing')
    .addItem('View/Edit My Routes', 'ViewMyRoutes')
    .addToUi();
}

function ViewMyRoutes() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('MyRoutes')
      .setTitle('My Routes')
      .setWidth(300);
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .showSidebar(html);
}
```

User.gs

```html
var User = function(){
  return {
    GetMyRoutes: function (){
      var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties(); 
      
      var routeData = userProperties.getProperty("SpreadsheetRoutes");
      
      return routeData;
    }
  };
}();
```

Sample.html

```html
<h1>Edit Route</h1>

<select id="EditRoute" onchange="LoadSelectedRoute()"></select>

<div id='divRoutes'></div>

<script>
  function LoadEditDropDown(){
    
    google.script.run
      .withFailureHandler(onFailure)
      .withSuccessHandler(OnGetRoutesSuccess)
      .User.GetMyRoutes();
  
    function OnGetRoutesSuccess(scriptProperties){  
    
      //do stuff with scriptProperties here
    }
  }
  
  LoadEditDropDown();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this? In such case, I use this way. But I don't know whether this is the best way. I'm sorry. I worry about that this may be the opposite way for you want.

### 1. Please add this function to GAS

```
function UserGetMyRoutes() {
    return User.GetMyRoutes();
}
```

### 2. Please modify `google.script.run` as follows

#### From :

```
google.script.run
  .withFailureHandler(onFailure)
  .withSuccessHandler(OnGetRoutesSuccess)
  .User.GetMyRoutes();
```

#### To :

```
google.script.run
  .withFailureHandler(onFailure)
  .withSuccessHandler(OnGetRoutesSuccess)
  .UserGetMyRoutes();
```